Error: Inputs do not conform to this spec or are otherwise invalid. (Building Cardano Transaction with dAPP wallet using Vanilla JS)
I'm trying to build a transaction with dApp wallet(s). Following is my code:
async function buildAndSignTransaction(api, recipientAddressStr, amount) {
    try {
        // Convert recipient address from Bech32
        const recipientAddress = wasm.Address.from_bech32(recipientAddressStr);
        console.log("Recipient Address From Bech32:", recipientAddress);

        // Step 1: Get used address (sender)
        const usedAddresses = await api.getUsedAddresses();
        const senderAddressHex = usedAddresses.length > 0 ? usedAddresses[0] : null;

        if (!senderAddressHex) {
            throw new Error("No sender address found.");
        }

        // Step 2: Create transaction builder
        const linearFee = wasm.LinearFee.new(
            wasm.BigNum.from_str("44"), // constant fee
            wasm.BigNum.from_str("155381")    // fee per byte
        );

        const minUtxoValue = wasm.BigNum.from_str("34482"); // minimum UTXO value of 1 ADA
        const poolDeposit = wasm.BigNum.from_str("500000000");
        const keyDeposit = wasm.BigNum.from_str("2000000");
        const coinsPerUtxoWord = wasm.BigNum.from_str("34482");
        const maxValueSize = 5000;
        const maxTxSize = 16384;

        const txBuilder = wasm.TransactionBuilder.new(
            linearFee,
            minUtxoValue,
            poolDeposit,
            keyDeposit,
            maxValueSize,
            maxTxSize
        );

        // Step 3: Get UTXOs and log them
        const utxos = await api.getUtxos();

        if (utxos.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("No UTXOs found for the sender.");
        }

        let totalInputValue = wasm.BigNum.from_str("0");
        let requiredAmount = wasm.BigNum.from_str(amount.toString());

        // Convert sender's address once before the loop
        const senderAddress = wasm.Address.from_bytes(hexToBytes(senderAddressHex));

        // Step 4: Select UTXOs
        for (const utxoHex of utxos) {
            const utxo = wasm.TransactionUnspentOutput.from_bytes(hexToBytes(utxoHex));
            const txInput = utxo.input();
            const outputValue = utxo.output().amount();

            const txHash = Buffer.from(txInput.transaction_id().to_bytes()).toString('hex');  // Transaction hash in hex
            const txIndex = txInput.index();  // Index of the input in the transaction

            console.log(". "+txHash + " #" + txIndex + " = " + outputValue.coin().to_str());

            // Ensure UTXO is valid and meets minimum value
            if (outputValue.coin().compare(minUtxoValue) < 0) {
                console.log("Skipping UTXO below minimum UTXO value:", outputValue.coin().to_str());
                continue; // Skip UTXOs that do not meet minimum value
            }

            txBuilder.add_input(
                senderAddress,
                txInput,
                outputValue
            );

            totalInputValue = totalInputValue.checked_add(outputValue.coin());
        }

        console.log("Total Input Value:", totalInputValue.to_str());
        console.log("Required Amount (Lovelace):", requiredAmount.to_str());

        // Step 5: Check if total input is enough
        const minFee = txBuilder.min_fee();
        console.log("Minimum Fee:", minFee.to_str());

        if (totalInputValue.compare(requiredAmount.checked_add(minFee)) < 0) {
            throw new Error('Not enough UTXO balance to cover the amount and fees.');
        }

        // Step 6: Add output for recipient
        const recipientAmount = wasm.BigNum.from_str(amount.toString());
        const outputAddress = wasm.Address.from_bytes(recipientAddress.to_bytes());

        console.log("Recipient Amount (Lovelace):", recipientAmount.to_str());
        console.log("Minimum UTXO Value (Lovelace):", minUtxoValue.to_str());

        if (recipientAmount.compare(minUtxoValue) < 0) {
            throw new Error(`Output amount ${recipientAmount.to_str()} is less than the minimum UTXO value ${minUtxoValue.to_str()}.`);
        }

        txBuilder.add_output(wasm.TransactionOutput.new(outputAddress, wasm.Value.new(recipientAmount)));
        console.log("Added Output - Recipient Address:", outputAddress, "Amount:", recipientAmount);

        // Step 7: Set the change (if any)
        const totalOutputValue = recipientAmount.checked_add(minFee);
        const changeAmount = totalInputValue.checked_sub(totalOutputValue);

        if (changeAmount.compare(wasm.BigNum.from_str("0")) > 0) {
            txBuilder.add_output(wasm.TransactionOutput.new(
                wasm.Address.from_bytes(hexToBytes(senderAddressHex)),
                wasm.Value.new(changeAmount)
            ));
            const senderAddress = wasm.Address.from_bytes(hexToBytes(senderAddressHex)).to_bech32().toString();
            console.log("Added Change - Address:", senderAddress, "Change Amount:", changeAmount.to_str());
        }

        // Step 8: Set fee
        txBuilder.set_fee(minFee);

        // Step 9: Build transaction
        const txBody = txBuilder.build();
        console.log("Transaction body built:", txBody);

        // Log the outputs manually
        const txOutputs = txBody.outputs();
        for (let i = 0; i < txOutputs.len(); i++) {
            const output = txOutputs.get(i);
            console.log(`Output ${i + 1}: Address: ${output.address().to_bech32()}, Amount: ${output.amount().coin().to_str()}`);
        }

        // Step 10: Build the full transaction with witness set
        const witnesses = wasm.TransactionWitnessSet.new();
        const transaction = wasm.Transaction.new(txBody, witnesses);
        console.log("Transaction with witnesses built:", transaction);

        // Step 11: Sign the transaction
        const signedTx = await api.signTx(transaction.to_bytes());
        console.log("Signed Transaction:", signedTx);

        // Step 12: Submit the signed transaction
        const txHash = await api.submitTx(signedTx);
        console.log("Transaction submitted. TX Hash:", txHash);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error building and signing transaction:", error);
    }
}


here API is nami, eternl, flint etc
I'm getting following error:
Inputs do not conform to this spec or are otherwise invalid.
Please note I'm using cardano-serialization-lib because I want to achieve this requirement in Vanilla JS, and for that I could only use this following cdn:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs@9.1.2/cardano_serialization_lib.min.js
I see so many examples where people are using ReactJS and their transaction builder looks something like this:
const txBuilder = TransactionBuilder.new(
            TransactionBuilderConfigBuilder.new()
                .fee_algo(LinearFee.new(BigNum.from_str(this.protocolParams.linearFee.minFeeA), BigNum.from_str(this.protocolParams.linearFee.minFeeB)))
                .pool_deposit(BigNum.from_str(this.protocolParams.poolDeposit))
                .key_deposit(BigNum.from_str(this.protocolParams.keyDeposit))
                .coins_per_utxo_word(BigNum.from_str(this.protocolParams.coinsPerUtxoWord))
                .max_value_size(this.protocolParams.maxValSize)
                .max_tx_size(this.protocolParams.maxTxSize)
                .prefer_pure_change(true)
                .build()
        );

But In my case I cannot use TransactionBuilderConfigBuilder as it is undefined in my cdn.
Please help me understand why I'm getting the error: Inputs do not conform to this spec or are otherwise invalid.
And if you guys can help me achieve this requirement in Vanilla JS that would be great!!
I appreciate your time reading this to help people like me.
